# Двумерные массивы в С++ - где ошибка?

Tags: c++, массивы

Мне нужно сделать сдвиг вправо в двумерном массиве и я придумал только такой метод (через переприсвоение значений), но программа не хочет етого делать и  просто выводит один и тот же масив.

```
const int SIZE_X = 3, SIZE_Y = 3;
int arr[SIZE_Y][SIZE_X];

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_Y; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_X; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_Y; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_X; j++)
    {
        int num = 0;
        num = arr[i][1];
        arr[i][1] = arr[i][0];
        arr[i][0] = arr[i][2];
        arr[i][2] = num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы же делаете этот сдвиг на один элемент 3 раза - `for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_X; j++)` - ну и получаете полный оборот... Если 3 раза повернуться на 120 градусов, куда вы будете смотреть? :)

Comment: Так і думав, що зробив дурну помилку, велике дякую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот код

```
for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_X; j++) 
{
    int num = 0;
    num = arr[i][1];
    arr[i][1] = arr[i][0];
    arr[i][0] = arr[i][2];
    arr[i][2] = num;
}
```

`SIZE_X` раз выполняет смещение на один элемент. Так как всего элементов `SIZE_X` - массив переходит в исходное состояние, сделав круг.